# error while send import request on kibana console

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I send following request on Kibana console to try to import a local dashboard to kibana version 7.2.0

```
POST https://dcwidavcca0085.epg.nam.gm.com:5601/api/saved_objects/_import
{
  "file"="C:\Users\Documents\dashboard-prod.ndjson"
}
```

however, I received error response

```
{
  "error": "no handler found for uri [/https://dcwidavcca0085.epg.nam.gm.com:5601/api/saved_objects/_import?pretty] and method [POST]"
}
```

I'm new to kibana API, the doc I'm following is https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.2/saved-objects-api-import.html
Is there any syntax/format error in my request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tldr;

Kibana's console in `7.2` only allow to target elasticsearch API.

You need to run the command in a terminal, using the `curl` command.

Comment: thanks. Do I need to install kibana to my laptop to run the command in terminal? I'm using web version of kibana

Comment: No you don't you should be using the terminal only. But it seems it is not a tools you a used to work with. Can't you upload your objects through the Graphical user interface ?

Comment: Yes, this is my first time work with kibana. I tried to import with graphical user interface, in setting->saved objects->import, but it failed to import with "the file could not be processed." So I want to run the api in terminal, to see whether it can give me some response message to see what's going on.

Comment: The dashboard I'm trying to import is from kibana 7.5.1, and I'm trying to import it to kibana 7.4.1 and 7.2.0. I'm not sure whether it is caused by version incompatibiliy.

Comment: You can check compatibility here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/saved-objects-api-import.html

Comment: when I run the command in terminal, "curl -X POST "https://dcwitavcca0236.epg.nam.gm.com:5601/api/saved_objects/_import" -H "kbn-xsrf: true" --form file=EKC-Dashboard-Prod.ndjson" it has error "{"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized"}". Is there anyway I can pass username and password to the command?

Comment: I found how to add username and password. but it has error "{"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"[security_exception] failed to authenticate user [user1], with { header={ WWW-Authenticate={ 0=\"Bearer realm=\\\"security\\\"\" & 1=\"ApiKey\" & 2=\"Basic realm=\\\"security\\\" charset=\\\"UTF-8\\\"\" } } }"}"

Comment: I run the curl api in kibana 7.4.1 dev tool console instead, it can send import request now. But it gives me response ""type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "json_parse_exception",
      "reason": "Unrecognized character escape 'U' (code 85)\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@33da7471; line: 2, column: 17]"
    }"